# reactive form validator won't work in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-validation

I have a validator of the type required and maxLength in my input field and I'm trying to have the cleanest code on my HTML. I tried to do the following but won't work

**HTML**

(this won't work)

```
<form [formGroup]="creditCardForm">
      <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="cardHolderName" required maxlength #cardHolderName/>
            <label *ngIf="form.cardHolderName.invalid &&
            (form.cardHolderName.dirty || form.cardHolderName.touched)" class="invalidField">Cardholder name is required</label>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
form = this.buildCreditCardForm(this.fb).controls;
.
.
buildCreditCardForm(fb: FormBuilder): FormGroup {
   return fb.group({
      cardHolderName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    .
    .
}
```

**HTML** (This works but it's too long, to dirty)

```
<form [formGroup]="creditCardForm">
<input type="text" pInputText formControlName="cardHolderName" required maxlength #cardHolderName/>
        <label *ngIf="fcreditCardForm.controls.cardHolderName.invalid &&
        (creditCardForm.controls.cardHolderName.dirty || creditCardForm.controls.cardHolderName.touched)" class="invalidField">Cardholder
          name is required</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Though the second way is the long as you feel, you can use only it. First one will through error.

Comment: @RohitSharma it didn't give me an error. just nothing happens. Do you have any other idea on how to make my code cleaner? I even tried having a method that returns a boolean and used it in the ngIf and the if statements inside of that method were what I currently have inside of the ngIf

Comment: You should check your console for error, it may be _can not read property cardHolderName of undefined_.

Comment: try to log your form you will see there is no ```cardHolderName``` property. so you can't access it via ```form.cardHolderName``` . the next way is correct and i think it's not dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mixing both reactive validators and template validators. not sure why you are complicating things, reactive forms are simple.

bulit you a [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udtwtx?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts) with your form:

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="creditCardForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="cardHolderName"/>
    <label *ngIf="creditCardForm.get('cardHolderName').invalid">Cardholder name is required</label>
</form>
```

**Component:**

```
  creditCardForm;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.creditCardForm = new FormGroup({
      'cardHolderName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)])
    });
  }
```

Take it away enhance and adjust to your needs.

Comment: You example is correct. I saw that in the angular docs before posting in here. This is my first time working with reactive forms and I didn't want to add the "new FormControl" and thought there was a cleaner way. Thanks!!

Comment: You have declared FormBuilder, but haven't used it for creation of a form